# discord bot(python) I'm making command code, but it's not working

Tags: discord.py

When I enter the !test command, I made it to output 1 first, but nothing is output.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')
    game = discord.Game('r')
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)

@bot.command(name='test')
async def t(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("1")
```

I hope the command works normally

Comment: Unrelated but don't change presence (or make any api calls) in `on_ready`. Just pass it to your `Bot`'s `__init__` directly... I wonder why everyone always does it in `on_ready` for no reason. Anyway, can you include more of your code? How are you running it? Is your bot even running? Is it online? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

game = discord.Game('r')
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents, activity=game)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')


@bot.command(name='test')
async def t(ctx): #should really be named test, as the command used to trigger is `!test`
    await ctx.reply("1")
```

First of all, I would not recommend making any API calls in on_ready, Discord has a high chance to completely disconnect you during the READY events and there is nothing you can do to prevent it. I get it, it seems like a logical spot to put it, but you will run into issues later on. I put the activity right next to the `command_prefix` and `intents` parameters, and defined the game activity above (set`'r'` to whatever you want).

Other than that, everything seemed to work. Instead of running the command using `!t`, I ran using `!test`. Unless you have different Privileged Intents than me (I have all enabled, enable them in the discord dev portal and set `intents = discord.Intents.all()`), everything should work perfectly.